# half transparent div above image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a PNG image of a character, and I want something like that:
http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1364482220.

If someone clicks on a part of the character's body, it'll be "selected".
The question is - how can I do that. I don't want to use more images (because I have multiple characters), I want to use CSS only.

I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/eRVpL/, but the green background appear above the white background, and I want it to be only above the character.

The code:

```
<div class="character">
    <img src="http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3854/goldgladiator.png" />
    <span></span>
</div>
<style>
.character { width: 210px;display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; }

.character > span {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30%;
    background: rgb(160, 255, 97);
    opacity: .3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
img {
    max-width: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You need to use a mask, image that will be exactly the same but the character transparent.

Comment: Is there any other way, without images? I have a lot of characters...

Comment: You can try to use canvas element and create mask using javascript. Or generate the mask using php. if the background is in one color the only thing you need to do is to make transparent what is not background.

Comment: The background is not one color...And how can I do it with canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work with [CSS masks](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking), although they are currently only supported in WebKit browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

http://jsfiddle.net/eRVpL/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="character">
  <img src="http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3854/goldgladiator.png">
  <div class="green-mask"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.green-mask {
  height: 200px;
  width: 508px;
  background: rgb(160, 255, 97);
  opacity: .3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3854/goldgladiator.png);
}
```

If you want to offset the elements like in the GIF you linked, put the colored background on children of the masked div:

http://jsfiddle.net/eRVpL/11/

HTML:

```
<div class="character">
  <img src="http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3854/goldgladiator.png">
  <div class="green-mask">
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filler {
  background-color: rgba(160, 255, 97, 0.3);
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.green-mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 508px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3854/goldgladiator.png);
}
```

And this one's just for fun: http://jsfiddle.net/eRVpL/23/ Try clicking the character. It uses checkboxes and labels with no JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks A lot!!!
Just at the time I wrote a comment to ask you what to do when the green block is in the middle, and then I noticed for your updating... LOL, you read mythoughts...
Thanks again, and sorry for my English

Comment: @ArielAharonson Sure thing, this was a fun problem. Keep in mind that CSS masks require alpha transparent PNGs like the character image you used in your original post. Masks clip an element to the non-transparent pixels in the PNG.

Comment: @ArielAharonson I'm not sure if you get updates about edits, but check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/eRVpL/23/

Comment: Thanks!!!! you are the man! one last thing if you can, I want it to be like in the SWF that I gave, If you press the legs, the stomach will be selected too. If you press the stomach, the shoulders will be selectted too, if you press the shoulders, the head will be selected too, and if you select the head, the legs will be selected too.Thanks A lot!

Comment: @ArielAharonson That should be easy with JavaScript. I was doing a JS-free version mainly to show that it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no CSS-only means of accomplishing this.  There is a specification for compositing and blending with CSS that's in the works, but it currently isn't being supported enough to be used in a product just yet.  You can read-up on the spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing/

With this specification, we could set the blend-mode of your  element to "screen", "overlay", or "lighten" which would make your character be green but the background would remain white.  Unfortunately, this isn't possible just yet.

The best way would be, as jcubic said in one of your comments, "You need to use a mask, image that will be exactly the same but the character transparent".

Good luck!

Comment: And it's not possible to do it with JS or something ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `z-index` for getting what you want. You'll  be able to make the object appear to be hidden on a certain page until you bring it up with a mouse click or hover. You can also make a green image that's basically a silhouette and cut it up into three different portions, give them a little bit of exact positioning (each with their own division) and have a little z-index, then you've got yourself that. You might also want to cut up the actual character into three parts to make it easier.

Comment: It's not a solution for my problem. I have a lot of characters, so if i'll use your solution, I'll have to make three images for each character, and it's a lot of job. My problem is that the green background appears above the white background, and I want it to be only above the character.